# C++ Learning Function Syntax

Tags: c++, function, syntax

I'm currently doing an assignment for my CS class and was confused how to use the syntax of the is Subset Function. I'm still working on the code. What I'm confused about is the (const Set &other) ... (I know that it implies one set and then another set) I'm just curious how to use it with my code. _numItems and _numItems2 are where I'm implying as to if thats where the (const Set &other) are used. Also, could I get help on how I would return this function. All help appreciated! Here's my code:

```
bool Set::isSubset(const Set &other) const
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _numItems2; i++) {
        for (int x = 0; i < _numItems; i++)
    }

    return 0;
}
```

// main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include "Set.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {

    Set s1, s2, s3;

    s1.addElement(7);
    s1.addElement(3);
    s1.addElement(5);
    s2.addElement(3);
    s2.addElement(5);
    std::cout << s1.containsElement(286) << endl;
    std::cout << s1.containsElement(7);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the function should return true if the set passed as a reference is contained within the calling set.
Example:
Set 1: 1 2 3 4
Set 2: 2 3

This iretuns true because set 1 contains 2 3 which is set 2

Comment: Thanks for you answer :), I'm actually aware of that, I'm just confused a little bit confused on what I would write where it says: _numItems2

Comment: bool Set::isSubset(const Set &other) const
{
 for (int i = 0; i < _numItemsSet2; i++) {
  for (int n = 0; n < _numItems; n++) {
   if (s1[i] == s2[n])
    break;
  }
  if (_numItemsSet2 == _numItems)
   return false;
 }
 
 return true;

Comment: I've updated the code a little bit. I'm also curious on what to put at s1 and s2

Comment: @jnestor Well, the other set is called "other", so that would be a good starting point. You should also review your book's chapter on functions from the very beginning.

Answer (score 1):

A simple iterative method:

```
bool Set::isSubset(const Set &other) const
{
    int j = 0;

    if(other.size() > size()) {
        return false;
    }

    //size() is the function or variable that denotes the number of elements in the set, replace as needed
    for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
        //if the j index is greater or equal to the size, all elements were found in order
        //therefore the set contains every portion of the subset
        if (j >= other.size()) {
            return true;
        }

        //if the items are the same, advance j index and advance i index by continuing to next iteration of loop
        if (*this[i] == other[j]) {
            j++;
            continue;
        }
        //otherwise, if they are not the same reset j index to 0 and start process of finding the subset again
        else {
            j = 0;
        }
    }

    //if i reaches the end of the main set and a subset is not found, it must not contain that subset therefore false
    return false;
}
```

This answer assumes that your class has a working `[]` operator

Comment: maybe move `other.size()` out of loop. whatever is bigger it can't be a subset.